# In a cylindrical bucket full of water where does the liquid apply maximum force on its WALL?

Tags: pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics

The height of the container is $h$. Please ignore the atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Integration
Take an element at a depth y of thickness dy
Let 'a' be the area of the base. Then,  Torque can be written as r cross df
where df=pgyady
And integrate it from 0 to h
You will find that maximum force would be found on the wall at a depth 2h/3.

Comment: did you take r from the base?

Comment: yes and the height from the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Water pressure increases by about 1.47 pounds per square inch for each meter of depth, exact pressure may vary slightly with purity and temperature. This means the greatest pressure will be at the lowest part of the container.